# Infopath Forms needs constant re-linking

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath

We have some legacy infopath forms hosted on SP 2013 forms library that we are in the plans of migrating to SharePoint Online .Recently we are seeing issues where the forms XML are not rendering in Browser .For a temporary fix we are clicking on re link all in the library settings and that seems to work for some time and after which the error is happening again .

Can you please let me know if there is any way that i can debug this more or at least find in advance if the forms broke so that i can re-link them before the users face issue .We still have to maintain this forms till they are ready to be migrated to SPO .Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i was able to write a script which re-links the documents and this is currently running as a scheduled task .Not a pretty solution but this should do the trick till we migrate them